# Importing custom .DLL C# library directly in Excel via VBA Declare statement

Tags: c#, excel, vba, dllimport

I'm trying to use a single function library done in C# in a VBA script, however I get this runtime error "Can't find DLL entry point Concatenate in .\EchoText.dll".

The **C#** Library code is this:

```
using System;

namespace EchoText
{
    public class EchoTextTools
    {
        public static string Concatenate(string text_1, string text_2)
        {
            return text_1 + text_2;
        }
    }
}
```

And the **VBA** code trying to use the previous .DLL Lib file is this one:

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function Concatenate Lib ".\EchoText.dll" (ByVal text_1 As String, ByVal text_2 As String) As String
#Else
    Private Declare Function Concatenate Lib ".\EchoText.dll" (ByVal text_1 As String, ByVal text_2 As String) As String
#End If


Public Sub hello()

    MsgBox Concatenate("Hello ", "World")
    
End Sub
```

The file "EchoText.dll" is located in the same folder as the Excel file running the previous vba macro.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a DLL just to concatenate strings? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142104/calling-a-dll-function-from-vba-excel-64-bit?rq=1 seems to suggest you need to use an explicit filepath, not sure whether that helps.

Comment: No, this is just a simple example, the main objective is really use heavy duty functions via DLL instead of the slower and limited VBA. These functions are time critical and VBA isn't up to the task.

Comment: Have a look e.g. [here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2013/10/make-a-c-dll-and-use-it-from-excel-vba-code/) and/or google for "how to create c# dll and use it in VBA".

Comment: That looks promising, I will try it and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Afaik the conditional compiling constant `VBA7` (Office 2010+) plays the main part in distinguishing if `PtrSafe` declarations are needed (changes to `LongPtr` for pointers to a → handle or → memory location) ,  the additional check `#If Win64 Then` might be necessary in only a few special functions   . - See [Declare API functions in 64bit Office](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/apideclarations.asp)

Comment: The c# dll doesn't export any functions. You'd need UnmanagedExports. There are countless posts on this topic you should search them.

Comment: Yes, I see many sites talking about this but is just suggestions and no solutions. That's why I tried asking, but looks like C# wasn't made to work with Office as I intended.